# why in the packaging.sys_tags() the lower cp version has higher priority than the py version which has no implementation spec?

Tags: python, python-packaging

from the document:

> The iterable is ordered so that the best-matching tag is first in the sequence. The exact preferential order to tags is interpreter-specific, but in general the tag importance is in the order of:
>
> 1. Interpreter
> 2. Platform
> 3. ABI

I would expect py310 before the cp39, however the pynn is always at the bottom:

```
import packaging.tags
print(list(dict.fromkeys(i.interpreter for i in packaging.tags.sys_tags())))
```

```
['cp310',
 'cp39',
 'cp38',
 'cp37',
 'cp36',
 'cp35',
 'cp34',
 'cp33',
 'cp32',
 'py310',
 'py3',
 'py39',
 'py38',
 'py37',
 'py36',
 'py35',
 'py34',
 'py33',
 'py32',
 'py31',
 'py30']
```

Does this means if I have old package `cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_35_x86_64` and the new package `py310-none-any`, given current system is cp310, it actually prefer the old package rather than the new py310-none-any? I cannot get my head around this. Why the order should be like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ... *old package `cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_35_x86_64` and the new package `py310-none-any`*

That would not be an "old package" and a "new package", but more like "platform specific package" and "general package". They'd be the same age.

The compat tags are nothing to do with the version number of the distribution itself. These are only considered when prioritizing files available when a particular version of a package has already been selected.

2. *Why the order should be like this?*

According to [docs](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/platform-compatibility-tags/#platform-compatibility-tags)

> It is recommended that installers try to choose the most feature complete built distribution available (the one most specific to the installation environment) by default before falling back to pure Python versions published for older Python releases.

Presumably, for built distributions, the more specific you can afford to be the more opportunity you have for platform-specific optimizations and the like. When building and publishing wheels, there may be some trade-offs to make when considering the competing desires of  wide compatibility vs advanced features.

An analogy in Python code might be: if you want to use the cooler new language features (e.g. use f-strings), you have to reduce your compatibility (e.g. restrict to Python 3.6+).

Comment: but cp36 will be compatible with cp310 at all? I doubt it. from https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/platform-compatibility-tags/, the example also only show cp33 and cp3 in front of py33, which make sense. I think the output without <cp310 will make more sense. And pip also behave as expected. It will never choose cp36 for cp310 system.

Comment: As far as I understood it, yes, cp36 tagged wheel should be compat with CPython 3.10. Don't quote me on this, but I think that tag means cpython >= 3.6, not cpython == 3.6. And yes, pip _will_ choose a cp36 wheel on 3.10 runtime if there is no _better_ cp10 wheel avail in the index. Use `pip debug -v` to show the compatible tags (and priority) for pip installer.

Comment: That example in the doc is a bit weird/vague.  It says "_This example list is for an installer running under CPython 3.3 on a linux_x86_64 system_" ... hmmm... what installer? Pip or something else? Or is it just some made up hypothetical installer? I don't quite understand what they're trying to communicate there.

Comment: hmm... this isn't true at all. I have many times the higher python minor version breaks the the lower python minor version. That is why in the setup.py you can specify something like python_requires <3.9, ok, I guess this means when that happens I will need to change setup.py and then bump up the package version instead of just rebuild/upload whl, then of course the problem would never happen.